# Angular part solutions of Schrodinger's equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations, spherical-harmonics

Hello Physics Community

i'm trying to solve the angular part of Schrodinger's equation, specifically the $\theta$ part ,
$$
\left[\sin \theta \frac{d}{d \theta}\left(\sin \theta \frac{d}{d \theta}\right)\right] P_{\ell}+\left(\sin ^{2} (\theta) C-m^{2}\right)  P_{\ell}=0
$$
Change the variable such that $\mu=$ $cos(\theta)$ and
$$
\frac{d}{d \theta}=\frac{d}{d\mu} \frac{d \mu}{d \theta}=-\sin \theta \frac{d}{d\mu}=-\sqrt{1-\mu^{2}}  \frac{d}{d \mu}
$$
\begin{array}{l}
=-\left(1-\mu^{2}\right) \frac{d}{d \mu}\left(-\left(1-\mu^{2}\right) \frac{d}{d \mu}\right) P_{\ell}+\left[\left(1-\mu^{2}\right) C-m^{2}\right] P_{\ell} \\
0=\frac{d}{d \mu}\left(\left(1-\mu^{2}\right) \frac{d}{d \mu}\right) P_{\ell}+\left[C-\frac{m^{2}}{1-\mu^{2}}\right]   P_{\ell} 
\end{array}
this is where the tricky part comes to role, my professor notes says that by applying the power series method, one can find out that for the above equations to have physically possible solutions, $C$ must be  $C=\ell(\ell+1)$.

How one can apply power series and get this value for the constant $C$  where $\ell$ is the positive integer (0,1,2,3....)? what is the significance of this value?

Comment: Have you learned about spherical harmonics and Legendre polynomials, check the Wiki...

Comment: You can replace $P_\ell$ by a series
$$P_\ell = \sum_\n c_n \mu^n$$ and solve term by term. You will probably (in the sense that I have not this in a long time and I am not sure of you messy it gets) find that, for the equations for each of the terms to have a solution C will need to have a value that is parametrized by a variable $\ell$, like that.

Comment: To expand on the comment of @JGBM , if you plug the Taylor expansion into the differential equation and equate terms of the same order in $\mu$, you will derive a series of *recursion relations* which fix the higher order coefficients $c_{n}$ in terms of lower order ones, $c_{n-1},c_{n-2}$. You will be able to fix $c_0,c_1$ from the boundary conditions, and this will allow you to solve each recursion relation in turn for the higher order coefficients. This problem is nice since you will only need a finite number of terms. The result will be the Legendre polynomials of degree $\ell$.